# How to run virtual environment from shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to setup my project environment from a shell script on ubuntu so that I can skip basic setup every time.

I use my virtual environmet `cv` using the command `workon cv`.

But I am having trouble doing so using a shell script. I tried the the script

```
#!/bin/bash

workon cv
```

But I get the error

```
workon: command not found
```

I try to list all the venv I have

```
pran@pran-HP-65-Notebook-PC:~$ lsvirtualenv
cv
==


virtual-py2
===========
```

Also, I thought of locating it

```
(cv) pran@pran-HP-65-Notebook-PC:~/.virtualenvs$ l
cv/               postdeactivate     preactivate*      prermvirtualenv*
get_env_details*  postmkproject*     predeactivate     virtual-py2/
initialize        postmkvirtualenv   premkproject*
postactivate      postrmvirtualenv*  premkvirtualenv*
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

My venv was located in `.virtualenvs`. So, I put the command in the bash file `start.sh` (meant to be executed before working on my project).

```
#start.sh
source ~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/activate
```

And run it using

```
$ source start.sh
```

It works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute `workon` command outside of Python virtual environment.

If you are interested, check out [this article](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_virtualenv_virtualenvwrapper.php) that will walk you through all of the steps required to set up your virutal env.

If it is not what you need then please clarify your requirements for a project environment.

Comment: why not use Anaconda?